# How to form a Cookie header from a cookiejar?

Tags: python

I have a `CookieJar` instance and I want to get a well-formed `Cookie:` HTTP header from its content.

I had a look at Python modules source code but it amounts to ~ 3/4 functions and 20 sloc, I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Note: I really want the header, not to make a `urllib` request with that cookies, and I know of `HTTPCookieProcessor` but it doesn't fit my needs (see above).

EDIT: If I was able to obtain a single `Cookie` (different thing, different module) object with the contents of the cookiejar, then it would be as easy as `.output(header="Cookie:")`. However,

> The cookielib and Cookie modules do not depend on each other.

Comment: You're looking for a more elegant solution than implemented in Python source code? Well... Make sure to issue a pull request when you're done ;-)

Comment: Hehe ;) Theirs is made to integrate directly into a `Request` object and to check for domain etc. I only need the header of all the cookies as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python uses [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python), you could instead pass in your own object to `add_cookie_header`; the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#cookiejar-and-filecookiejar-objects) even lists the methods you would need to implement (`get_full_url`, `get_host`, etc.), although it's probably just simpler to create a temporary `urllib.request.Request` object and then fetch the cookie from it and do what you want with it.

(Of course, you *could* call internal methods like `_cookie_attrs` but I assume you know why that's a bad idea—it's brittle to depend on implementation details like that.)